# HAproxy reqirep not working properly (missing escape?)

Tags: google-app-engine, http, haproxy

This is not working:

```
reqirep ^Host:\ beta.domain.com   Host:\ beta.app-id.appspot.com
```

however everything is working fine if I change this reqirep to this:

```
reqirep ^Host:\ beta.domain.com   Host:\ primary.domain.com
```

reqirep procedure is working correctly. In first example "app-id" is an Google App Engine application ID with "-" (dash) character.

What am I missing in the first case? I tried escaping dash ("-"), but this does not solve this issue. I am running HAproxy 1.4.8

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to escape the hyphen.

It sounds like you're having trouble routing to the correct `server`. Verify you are using the correct IP in the `server` endpoint.